# Sending over a number from Arduino to Attiny85

Tags: arduino-uno, communication, attiny85

I recently started my first arduino project, displaying a number on a 4x 7 segment display. I want to keep this code and use the display in other projects to display 4 digit numbers (creating a library and using segmentdisplay.write(number) maybe?).

Just displaying the number went really well, but I wanted to drive it with less I/O pins. Then I discovered shift registers, which reduced the number of necessary I/O pins to 3. But, the code needs to execute constantly to keep the 4 digits on the display via multiplexing. My solution to this was to run the sketch on attiny85, on which I programmed the code below. The only thing left to do is to change the value of 'getal' to a value that I read or calculate on the arduino. But I have no idea on how to achieve this, can I shift out data from the arduino to attiny85, which then updates 'getal's value? Any help is appreciated!

```
const int dataPin = 0;
const int latchPin = 1;
const int clockPin = 2;

const int Db = B00001111;
const int D1 = B00000111;
const int D2 = B00001011;
const int D3 = B00001101;
const int D4 = B00001110;
const int num0 = B11111100;
const int num1 = B01100000;
const int num2 = B11011010;
const int num3 = B11110010;
const int num4 = B01100110;
const int num5 = B10110110;
const int num6 = B10111110;
const int num7 = B11100000;
const int num8 = B11111110;
const int num9 = B11110110;

int D_4[4] = {D1, D2, D3, D4};
int D_3[4] = {Db, D2, D3, D4};
int D_2[4] = {Db, Db, D3, D4};
int D_1[4] = {Db, Db, Db, D4};
const int num[10] = {num0, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9};

const int tallen[4] = {1000, 100, 10, 1};

int getal = 185;

void setup() {
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  int lengte = findn(getal);
  switch (lengte) {
    case 1:
      displaynum(D_1);
      break;
    case 2:
      displaynum(D_2);
      break;
    case 3:
      displaynum(D_3);
      break;
    case 4:
      displaynum(D_4);
      break;
  }
}

int findn(int num) {
  int n = 0;
  while (num) {
    num /= 10;
    n++;
  }
  return n;
}

void displaynum(int *D_x) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

    digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);

    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, D_x[i]);
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, num[(getal / tallen[i]) % 10]);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you setup the display to run on a timer-driven interrupt, you can still do many other things and the display will update via the timer(say every 5ms)

Comment: Hardware i cheaper that your time; buy a LCD or OLED display.

Comment: I obviously know that buying a screen is cheaper, I just want to learn this.

Comment: While the tiny85 does not have a complete hardware I2C, I believe you can do a hardware-"assisted" I2C interface which may be more suitable for transferring a multi-byte value than asynchronous serial.  Beware though that debugging multiprocessor systems can rapidly become complicated; doing background operations on the main ATmega may ultimtely prove simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Look Alterno stated it would be easier to directly use an LCD display. But if you really want to use the 7 segment display and the ATTiny85 you can use I2C to send the number to the ATTiny. There are libraries, that can use the USI hardware ot emulate a (nearly) full I2C bus. For example my [TinyWire library](https://github.com/lucullusTheOnly/TinyWire), that I composed from the previous TinyWireM and TinyWireS libraries. I2C needs only 2 pins (pin 0 as SDA and pin 2 as SCL I think), so you still have your 3 pins left for the display.

Then you would make the Arduino master and the ATTiny slave. Use the examples, that come with the library to learn it's usage. Note, that currently you can use the `write()` function only with one byte, so if you need bigger datatypes you need to split them to byte-level on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Could also use a chip with better resources, such as Attiny2313. 20 Pins, so a little larger than the '85, but you get a real serial port and SPI port.